# Detecting object types in JSON document

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a text file as input which contains `Employee`s. Now I need to refactor the code and the JSON can either contain an `Employee[]` array or a `Building[]` array. I am using Jackson, and there are enums in my Java class.

```
{
    Employee[]
}

{
    Building[]
}
```

I have code to selectively parse each document, but how can the code detect whether it is an `Employee` doc or a `Building` doc?

I know it's kind of a bad design, but there are some constraints for which I am doing so.

I need something like this:

```
boolean isBuildingDoc(String json);

boolean isEmployeeDoc(String json);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try with `gson`, it converts json into classes.

Comment: Using ObjectMapper.readValue(File, Class) you would get exceptions when there is a mapping issue. So I guess you could try Building first, then Employee if you want to follow that route.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to add a top level property to your json called 'info'.

For example:

```
{
  "info": {
    "document_type": "employee"
  },
  "content": {
    // rest of your json goes here...
  }
}
```

Put the old json you used to generate in 'content'. Then, when you parse your json file, you can easily check the info.document_type flag to see what document type you are working with.

However, if you do not have control over the json that is being parsed (e.g. if it is being sent from another program), then this approach will not work.

Comment: cant do it. Actually i am refectoring an api which takes old json .Now i need to support old as well as new json

Answer (score 0):

You can use tree modal of jackson to detect `Employee` or `Building` node.
E.g.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

if(node.get("Employee") != null){
//handle it according to employee
}
else if(node.get("Building ") != null){
//handle it according to building
}
```

Note : Do remember one thing, `get` method searches for field in child elements also, So if your `Employee` array contains `Building` field as a child element, then this method will not work.